# TeamViewer Hack

Tags: teamviewer

A friend and I had been using TeamViewer, and not long after that he had been hacked. He had said that the hacker came in through my computer into his. Is this possible? Did I allow the hacker in to his computer for the hacker to destroy his computer? He says the hacker is still sitting in my computer but I see no trace of anything, is this possible?

Comment: More information is required to say anything of value, like are you in the same subnet? How do your computers usually talk to each other? what is the significance of teamviewer here (as it is in your title) and what were you both doing when this "hack" occurred? It is in theory possible... but the likelihood of a hacker targeting that guy specifically and the only method was through you somehow is very VERY small... so this seems unlikely to me. Possible, but not likely.

Comment: in general, take hacking allegations with a grain of salt. if he were expert enough to determine such specific causality, he should be expert enough not to get hacked in the first place...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "destroy his computer"?

Comment: No we are not on the same subnet, we used teamviewer so he could see if he could work out why my computer was slugging so much.

Comment: His video card and motherboard became unusable apparently, the settings on his computer continuously got changed and the hacker was apparently leaving messages on his computer and now apparently tapping into his phone as he hears beeps, and the beeps only occur when I call him

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because taking the comments into account, this is obviously some kind of trolling.

Comment: So I am not allowed to ask questions to find out if what he is saying is true or not, I do not know how much of what he said happened is true and I am searching for clarification, I am sorry if that makes me a troll

Comment: @Loriex: very little of it's likely true, except to your friend, for which it's stone-cold reality.

Comment: @dandavis thank you, I appreciate that, it puts my mind at ease. He had me convinced.